# file_get_contents(URL) returns failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, web, proxy, ip

I am Scrapping a website, Since data is TOO Much big, and I can't keep my Laptop always open, I am using RDP to scrap it.

Now they have blocked up my RDP IP so that I can't access that website, IF i install any VPN, Proxy Software (Since it changes my IP address), I would loose acces to my RDP, than I have to contact RDP PRovider to uninstall it so I am able to access RDP.

Is there any solution to access this website via RDP ? I came to know about Socks5, Website open fines when I use Socks5 with Mozilla it works fine but when I use localhost and run the script, I get file_get_contents(URL) returns failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden. since XAMPP sends HTTP requests via Network IP rather than browser IP.

Anyway to Overcome this problem ?

Comment: It sounds like what you're doing is not legal. So you shouldn't do this anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using cURL.

```
<?php

    $curl_handle=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,'http://###.##.##.##/mp/get?mpsrc=http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/11111.mpg&mpaction=convert format=flv');
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Your application name');
    $query = curl_exec($curl_handle);
    curl_close($curl_handle);

    ?>
```